# Vue MultiSelect tells me I have selected all when I have only selected one value

Tags: vuejs2, vue-multiselect

First time using vue multiselect and I got it displaying data correctly but when i select one option and go back to select another it tells me all are selected. However my vue dev tools tels me only one is showing in the values.

```
<multiselect v-model="value" track-by="id" label="name" :options="repos" multiple></multiselect>
```

I saw a similar question here [Error in implementing Vue multiselect properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468432/error-in-implementing-vue-multiselect-properly) However from what I can tell none of my id's are the same which is what i have told multiselect to track by.

Screenshots below

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am a fool!!! I was using id when clearly from the rather large screenshot the paramater is named value.

Same fix as [Error in implementing Vue multiselect properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468432/error-in-implementing-vue-multiselect-properly)

Apologies for the duplicate